# Difference in MEG and EEG readings

Tags: eeg, electrophysiology, brain-waves, meg

Reading the [excellent clear answer from @RobinKramer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/15223/7604) to [Are brain waves electromagnetic waves?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15222/are-brain-waves-electromagnetic-waves) I have become very interested in the mechanisms behind the measurement techniques using EEG and MEG.

From the answer, I understand that an EEG measures the action potentials within a neuron from one end to the other and a MEG measures the magnetic field generated by the action potentials. What I am wondering is; generally speaking, will the waveform outputs from each measuring device mirror each other in frequency and µV scales or are they different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood how the outputs may be viewed from an MEG.

Magnetoencephalography (MEG) is a non-invasive test, which:

> measures the magnetic fields generated by electric currents in the brain. The magnetic field measurements are in the range of femto-tesla to pico-tesla. MEG provides a very accurate resolution of the timing of neuronal activity ([Singh, 2014](https://doi.org/10.4103/0972-2327.128676)).

A copyrighted image of an MEG recording can be viewed in [Figure 3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4001219/figure/F3/) of Singh (2014) and looks very different to a normal EEG with a typical montage, which can be viewed in [Figure 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK390346/figure/f01/?report=objectonly) within [Louis, et al. (2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK390346/).

### References

Louis, E. K. S., Frey, L. C., Britton, J. W., Hopp, J. L., Korb, P., Koubeissi, M. Z., ... & Pestana-Knight, E. M. (2016). The normal eeg. Electroencephalography (EEG): An Introductory Text and Atlas of Normal and Abnormal Findings in Adults, Children, and Infants [Internet]. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK390346/

Singh S. P. (2014). Magnetoencephalography: Basic principles. *Annals of Indian Academy of Neurology, 17*(Suppl 1), S107–S112. https://doi.org/10.4103/0972-2327.128676